# How can I handle different versions of word TV in list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

While pulling some amenities data from the site insideairbnb,I noticed there were different types of TVs.

```
tv_list = [["TV","water","Gas","wifi"], ["HDTV","shower"],["50//TV",'sauna'],["TV with Roku","a bunch of stuff"],["Cable TV"],["suana","bathtub","Direct TV","couch","spinach"]]
```

What I want to do is change all strings with TV to TV.  Example "HDTV" would become TV. "TV with Roku" would become "TV". But I cannot account for all the different types.  Can someone please assist?

```
for element in tv_list:
    if "TV" or "HDTV" or "Cable TV" in element:
        for i in range(len(element)):
            if "TV"in element[i]:
                element[i] ="TV"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in each element of `list` is existing `TV` or not, If `TV` is existing insert `TV` instead of all words.

```
for row, lst in enumerate(tv_list):
    for col, item in enumerate(lst):
        if 'TV' in item:
            tv_list[row][col] = 'TV'
print(tv_list)
```

OR with [`list comprehensions`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
res = [['TV' if 'TV' in item else item for item in lst] for lst in tv_list ]
```

---

```
[
    ['TV', 'water', 'Gas', 'wifi'], 
    ['TV', 'shower'], 
    ['TV', 'sauna'], 
    ['TV', 'a bunch of stuff'], 
    ['TV'], 
    ['suana', 'bathtub', 'TV', 'couch', 'spinach']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

"TV" in element, should account for all the possibilities you specified above. But you should still be aware of exceptions where "TV" is not inside the TV-Data-String

**This one here could be one possibility, but Why do you check first if there is any TV inside.... That's like checking two times one thing**

```
for element in tv_list:
    if  any( map(lambda x: "TV" in x, element)):
        for i in range(len(element)):
            if "TV"in element[i]:
                element[i] ="TV"
```

this one here should be more efficient

```
for element in tv_list:
        for i in range(len(element)):
            if "TV" in element[i]:
                element[i] ="TV"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do so with a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps). This is given in another answer, but with the slight improvements that it is not a nested comprehension, which can be a bit more clear, and it matches even lower case instances of "tv".

```py
updated = []
for ammenities in tv_list:
    updated.append(["TV" if "tv" in a.lower() else a for a in ammenities])
```

This, if printed gives:

```
[
    ["TV", "water", "Gas", "wifi"],
    ["TV", "shower"],
    ["TV", "sauna"],
    ["TV", "a bunch of stuff"],
    ["TV"],
    ["suana", "bathtub", "TV", "couch", "spinach"],
]
```

You may also want to check for "television":

```py
updated = []
for ammenities in tv_list:
    updated.append(
        [
            "TV" if "tv" in a.lower() or "television" in a.lower() else a
            for a in ammenities
        ]
    )
```